# How to tell scrapy crawler to STOP following more links dynamically?

Tags: python, scrapy

Basically I have a regex rule for **following** pages

Each page has 50 links

When i hit a link that is too old (based on a pre-defined date-time)

I want to tell scrapy to stop following more pages, but NOT stop it entirely, it must continue to scrape the links it has already decided to scrape -> (complete all `Request` objects created). JUST that it must NOT follow any more links. So the program will eventually grind to a stop (when it's done scraping all the links)

Is there any way i can do this inside the spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy's `CrawlSpider` has an internal `_follow_links` member variable which is not yet documented (experimental as for now)

setting `self._follow_links = False` will tell scrapy to stop following more links. But continue to finish up all the `Request` objects it has already created

Answer (score 0):

Once you hit the "too old" page, throw the [`CloseSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider) exception. In this case, Scrapy would finish processing links being scheduled and then shut down.

Comment: Will the "graceful" shutdown allow scrapy to scrape the remaining links it has inside in its queue? (All the `Request` object calls must have been processed)

Comment: @wolfgang from what I understand from reading the source code, yes, it is a "graceful" shutdown - but, please, better test it first.

Comment: I tried it, Scrapy does'nt seem to be crawling all the links it has in its "queue"  the stopping point appears arbitary (i'm assuming after it has "gracefully" cleaned up other resources)

Answer (score 0):

Raise the CloseSpider exception from a callback.

```
def parse_page(self, response):
if 'Bandwidth exceeded' in response.body:
    raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
```